# VBA MS Word Determining Object Type

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use the following code to determine if the selected range is an equation or not:

```
    If TypeOf Selection.Range Is OMath Then
    MsgBox ("yes")
    Else
    MsgBox ("NO")
    End If
```

but even when the selected range is already an equation the msgbox says "No"
Is there any way to solve this

Comment: `TypeOf Selection.Range` will always be `Range`.

Comment: Since an equation is a statement that the values of two mathematical expressions are equal (indicated by the sign =), then you can use this one liner `If InStr(1, Selection, "=") > 0 Then MsgBox "Yes" Else MsgBox "No"`

Comment: You can check `Selection.OMaths.Count` to see if an equation is in the selection.